# I am having trouble getting this SQL statement to filter the table by a starting date and ending date field

Tags: sql, filemaker

I am having trouble getting this SQL statement to filter the table by a starting date and ending date field. All the fields are in the same table and I am not sure if I have formulated something incorrectly... I am obviously new to SQL thanks in advance for any assistance you might provide.

```
ExecuteSQL (
"
SELECT sum (Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_1 
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_2
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_3
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_4
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_5
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_6
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_7
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_8
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_9
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_10)
FROM TABLE
WHERE Billing_Tab_Name_1 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_2 = ‘Employee Name’
OR Billing_Tab_Name_3 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_4 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_5 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_6 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_7 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_8 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_9 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_10 = 'Employee Name'
AND Billing_Tab_Date_1 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date and        Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_2 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_3 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_4 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_5 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_6 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_7 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_8 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_9 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_10 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
"
; "" ; "" )
```

Comment: If you fix the file format (to have just one row per date) then this query (and probably others) will be much simpler.

Comment: When mixing AND and OR comparisons in the where clause, it is often good to add parenthesis and group them carefully.

Comment: the problem is that the result of the formula is ignoring ALL the starting date and ending date clauses. It returns total ours for the employee for the table

Answer (score 0):

try this:

if you do not care about matching the Billing_Tab_name with Billing_Tab_hours then you can use this:

```
ExecuteSQL ("
SELECT sum (Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_1 
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_2
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_3
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_4
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_5
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_6
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_7
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_8
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_9
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_10)
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Billing_Tab_Name_1 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_2 = ‘Employee Name’
OR Billing_Tab_Name_3 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_4 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_5 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_6 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_7 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_8 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_9 = 'Employee Name'
OR Billing_Tab_Name_10 = 'Employee Name')
AND (Billing_Tab_Date_1 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date and        Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_2 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_3 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_4 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_5 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_6 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_7 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_8 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_9 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date
OR Billing_Tab_Date_10 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
"; "" ; "" )
```

But if they have to match then you need this:

```
ExecuteSQL ("
SELECT sum (Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_1 
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_2
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_3
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_4
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_5
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_6
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_7
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_8
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_9
+ Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_10)
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Billing_Tab_Name_1 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_1 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date and        Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_2 = ‘Employee Name’ AND Billing_Tab_Date_2 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_3 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_3 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_4 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_4 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_5 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_5 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_6 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_6 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_7 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_7 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_8 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_8 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_9 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_9 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date)
OR (Billing_Tab_Name_10 = 'Employee Name' AND Billing_Tab_Date_10 BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date) 
"; "" ; "" )
```

Comment: Is it really ok if billing name 1 was an employee and billing date 9 is within the desired range?  Or does the billing name and billing date need to match for the corresponding number (for example: name 1 and date 1)?

Comment: it all really depends on what is the criteria. the query as its been shown in the question does not seem right. @DavidCram thanks I have now updated the answer to include both conditions. but really there should be more description in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes the billing_tab_name_# must match the billing_tab_hours_total_#

Comment: @Jim ok then the second query is what you need. Just one more question. can you post some sample data from your table so that I can see how the Billing_Tab_Hours_Total_# fields are populated because you may need to use CASE statements within the SUM() function.

Comment: Billing_Tab_Hours_Total is the result of a calculated field as where four (4) fields are summed to calculate the total hours Select Sum (field1 + field2 + field 3 + field 4) all of the four (4) fields are number fields

Comment: as clarification the form for this table is a place where a employee can record (his/her) hours for a task of a job... I tried to paste a picture of the form to better illustrate what I am trying to do, but it would not work. I think your correct, the formula you provided does not return a result

Comment: @JimCox sorry without any knowledge of what the data within your table looks like its hard to comment. Assuming your table is not empty ;)  reason why query is not returning any results is because Billing_Tab_Name_# = ‘Employee Name’ AND Billing_Tab_Date_# BETWEEN Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date for [1-10] do not either fall in the Report_Starting_Date AND Report_Ending_Date or Billing_Tab_Name_# does not equal ‘Employee Name’ or both.